# Show that $\frac{1}{n}X_n\to 0$ a.s.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, proof-verification

> > Show that for any sequence $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in (L_{\mathbb{P}}^2)^{\mathbb{N}}$ of identically distributed random variables it is $\frac{1}{n}X_n\to 0\text{ a.s.}$.

The professor suggested to use *Borel-Cantelli*.

I define
$$
E:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}X_n(\omega)\neq 0\right\}
$$
and have to show that $\mathbb{P}(E)=0$.

In order to use Borel-Cantelli, my idea is to re-write $E$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$ as
$$
E=\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \frac{1}{n}\lvert X_n(\omega)\rvert > \varepsilon~\text{ for }\infty-\text{ many } n\right\}=\limsup_n A_n.
$$
with
$$
A_n:=\left\{\frac{1}{n}\lvert X_n\rvert > \varepsilon\right\}.
$$
I want to show that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\mathbb{P}(A_n)<\infty$. Then it would follow that $\mathbb{P}(\limsup_n A_n)=\mathbb{P}(E)=0$.

---

But I do not know if this is the right strategy and if yes, how to show that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\mathbb{P}(A_n)<\infty$, especially how to use that $X_n\in L_{\mathbb{P}}^2$ and that the $X_n$ are identically distributed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being $L^1$ is enough since
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant1}P(A_n)\leqslant E(|X_1|)/\varepsilon.
$$
To show this, recall that, for every $n$, $P(A_n)=P(|X_1|\geqslant n\varepsilon)$ since $X_n$ and $X_1$ are identically distributed, and note that $P(|X_1|\geqslant n\varepsilon)=E(\mathbf 1_{|X_1|\geqslant n\varepsilon})$ and
$$
\varepsilon\sum_{n\geqslant1}\mathbf 1_{|X_1|\geqslant n\varepsilon}\leqslant|X_1|.
$$

Comment: I do understand nearly everything but not why $\sum_{n\geq 1}\mathbb{E}(1_{\lvert X_1\rvert\geq n\varepsilon})=\varepsilon\sum_{n\geq 1}1_{\lvert X_1\rvert\geq n\varepsilon}\leq\lvert X_1\rvert$.

Comment: This is not what I wrote. Rather, I stated that $g(x)\leqslant|x|$ for every $x$, where $g(x)=\varepsilon\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\mathbf 1_{|x|\geqslant n\varepsilon}$. Can't you show this?

Comment: Okay, using this statement it is $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\mathbb{P}(A_n)\leqslant \frac{1}{\varepsilon} E(\lvert X_1\rvert)<\infty$, right?

Comment: Second line of my post.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that you are too fast for me. :-)